# How do I remove a Guide from my "Handbook" on guides.co?

Tags: guides.co

I have just started with [Guides.co](http://guides.co/) and viewed a free guide.

Now the free guide is showing up in my "Handbook" home page. How do I remove this guide from my handbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Handbook" page is like the library page on the Kindle. It shows you what content you have access to and re-arranges them based on last opened.

Currently there is no way to "delete" or archive a Smart Guide you have accessed (but it is something that will be added.

Hope that helps!